# iFrame Issue with Page Load in Headless Browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, headless

I'm facing an issue where my Selenium script using a headless browser (Chrome) doesn't fully load the page and page is in iframe.

[I have an HTML content image that displays our HTML content. Could you please review it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTSal.png)

[As you can observe in the image below, after using a headless browser, the page does not load.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Irr.png)

**Find the below code for understanding**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            if (!System.getProperty("browserMode").equalsIgnoreCase("normal"))
                options.addArguments("--incognito");
            options.addArguments("--headless=new");
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
```

```
UIDriver.waitUntilElementInvisible("ONB.waitIndicator", 7);
        UIDriver.setValue("ONB.reportSearch", input.get("reportName"));
        UIDriver.clickElement("ONB.reportSearchBtn");
        UIDriver.waitUntilElementInvisible("ONB.waitIndicator", 7);
        UIDriver.clickElementDynamic("ONB.reportActions", input.get("reportName"));
        UIDriver.clickElement("ONB.reportRunBtn");
        UIDriver.wait(5);
        UIDriver.switchToFrameToIt("sac-embed-iframe");

        //driver.switchTo().frame(1);

        UIDriver.waitUntilElementInvisible("ONB.waitIndicator", 15);
        UIDriver.waitUntilElementVisible("ONB.reportTitle", 10);
        UIDriver.clickElement("ONB.reportTitle");
        UIDriver.clickElement("ONB.reportMoreActions");
        UIDriver.wait(3);
```

Problem: as elements not being found or the page not rendering completely.

Error Messages: Unable to find the elements.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!